# TexStudio: how to "bold" rapidly a sentence with \textbf{...}

Tags: texstudio, text

Let's say that I want to highlight some words or some entire sentences in a `.tex` file. And assume I am using `TexStudio` as editor.

Is there the possibility of highlighting the whole word/sentence with the mouse and (maybe with a shortcut or a key combination) embed everything in `\textbf{sentence to be highlighted}` ?

Comment: They are called personal macros. http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#SECTION33

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's standard TeXstudio possibility: highlight `some text` by mouse and press `Ctrl + B` and whereupon you get `\textbf{some text}`.

Comment: +1 this works and this the option I was looking for. Thanks

Comment: This of course will work as well :)

Answer (score 4):

This should work, especially if you want to do more than just make it bold. Put that in the personal macros entry.

```
%SCRIPT
var text=cursor.selectedText()

if(text.length>0)
{
    //cut selected text
    cursor.removeSelectedText()
    editor.write("\\textbf{");
    editor.write(text);
    editor.write("}");
}
```

Based on: https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/wiki/Scripts

In TexStudio (sorry german)

[image]
[image]

Then select Text

[image]

Hit (in my case Shift+F2) And there it is

[image]

Comment: +1 it works and, thanks to your answer, I am discovering the MACRO in latex! Thank you

Comment: I am discovering a wonderful world! Where can I found the list of actions that can trigger a macro?

Comment: @Leos313 In embedded user manual, subsection 4.5 "Personal macros".

Comment: @Sango, I must say your solution provided me some new knowledge and ideas for macros ... *but*, in this specific case, how is this better than just `Ctrl + B`? Would it be the *exact operation* that TeXstudio performs through the keyboard shortcut?

Comment: I just didn't think about `Ctrl+B`, so thats the reason i did it this way. BUT as said, this has the potential to do more than just bold. Thats my excuse for keeping it :)