# TeXStudio macro multiple cursor placements?

Tags: macros, texstudio

I am attempting to write a basic macro in TexStudio. I want to write

> fr

and have `$\frac{}{}$` appear instantly. I want my cursor placed first in the numerator, then when I press Tab, it goes to the denominator. I know that I can place my cursor with `%|`, but how would I set my cursor to move to the denominator when I hit tab and then leave the `$` after I hit tab once more? Can this be done with just a macro, or do I have to write a short script macro to get this done?

In short, is there a multiple cursor placement command? If not, what editor does handle this operation? I'm on Windows, if that matters.

Comment: Hi @trytryagain and welcome to TeX-SE. Have you seen [How to put placeholder in macros in TexStudio](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/151289/140133) and also [TexStudio: how to “bold” rapidly a sentence with \textbf{…}](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/526911/140133)?